# Sound Troubles with 12.04 on Dell Latitude D420

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

When upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04 sound playback with internal speakers stopped working on my Dell Latitude D420 laptop.  Before the upgrade I'd had intermittent problems with sound, mostly with recording, but recording seems to be working now.

If I run `mplayer /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` I get no sound.

If I run `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` I get no sound.

If I run `aplay -l` I get two sound devices:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: STAC92xx Digital [STAC92xx Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In Audacity I have twelve sound output choices:

```
HDA Intel STAC92xx Analog (hw0:0) - works
HDA Intel STAC92xx Digital (hw0:1) - no sound
sysdefault - works
front - works
surround40 - works
surround51 - works
surround71 - works
iec958 - no sound
spdif - no sound
pulse - no sound
dmix - works
default - no sound
```

If I run "aplay -L" to list PCMs I get:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Analog
    Default Audio Device
...
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, STAC92xx Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

If I run `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav -D default` I get no sound.

If I run `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav -D hw` I get no sound and an error message: `aplay: set_params:1087: Channels count non available`.

If I run `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav -D plughw` it works and I hear "Front Center". `-D sysdefault` also works.

When I turn the computer on it makes the startup chime properly.

When I open the "Sound" program on the "Output" tab it has one option for "Play Sound Through": "Digital Output (S/PDIF) *Built-in Audio*".  When I plug in headphones another option appears there: "Headphones *Built-in Audio*".  Selecting that option works and gives me sound in all programs, though if I run the `aplay -D sysdefault` command I now get:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:682: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 2):

Along the Ubuntu Desktop at the top near the system clock, Click on Sound Icon and then select sound settings, and then select the Speakers (Built in Audio) and make sure you raise the Output sound volume..

Comment: This doesn't work; even if the volume is all the way up there's still no sound.